# Magento 2 Search not finding SKU with special chars in it

Tags: magento2, search, special-character

if we search for an sku string with hashtag (e.g. "QW49ES#ABD") search results page shows me many many results (i guess all results with hashtag in it).

If i only search for the sku part "QW49ES" i receive the correct single result.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks,
hamipl

Comment: have you found any solution on this?